# How to ensure that input entered is unique?

Tags: php, html, submit

I have a simple form that is submitted in a database. One of the fields need to be unique (therefore i have declared its corresponding column as unique). It works ok and doesn't post any repeated values. So far so good.
But i also wanted to add a message (like the one when i try to submit numeric values into non - numeric fields etc). This message will tell the user that the value already exists. Here i am posting a screenshot taken from w3schools. This is the format I want to use:

[image]

I can add on the submit.php file some lines that search if the value already exists or not. However, how do i display that message? (Since the validation is server side while the message is displayed in the client side)?

After the request of Jordy, I am posting a code. Even though is a standard one.

html file:

```
<form action="add_classroom.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="number" placeholder="Name" name="classroom_id" required>
</form>
```

php code (add_classroom.php):

```
$result = pg_query(connect(), "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM classroom WHERE classroom_id = '$_POST[classroom_id]'");
$count = pg_fetch_all($result);
//if it exists, do sth (havent figured out what yet)
if($count[0]['count'] == 1){
    $result = pg_query(connect(), "INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('$_POST[classroom_id]', '$_POST[building]', '$_POST[floor]', '$_POST[capacity]')");
}

else    $result = pg_query(connect(), "INSERT INTO classroom VALUES ('$_POST[classroom_id]')");
```

And in the table declaration, classroom_id was declared unique. Which prevents existing data from being inserted. So No need to take care of that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to insert the data, check whether it exists, and echo that response. Otherwise, insert the data.

For example, using Mysqli

```
// Store '1' if already exists
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE field = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$value);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($exists);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if($exists){
   echo 'Already exists';
}
else
{
  // insert the data
}
```

Comment: I have, it still answers your question. To format the output just add HTML, ie echo "<p class='myerror'>Needs to be unique</p>";

Comment: If you read it, you will see that I dont want to define a format of my own. I want to use the one html5 uses.

Comment: Considering you don't know how to do it, and other people on here do and may offer to help you, I'd suggest losing the attitude.

Comment: It's not about the attitude. I am admitting I have no idea how to do it. But people here are giving me unrelated answers. So I am trying to point out what it is that they are missing in their answers.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to query the database to see if the value exists, or what you can do is check the rows returned from the query, if its 1 (means something is inserted) you know that the value was unique, if it returns 0, then it means that the name was already in use.

If you wanna however 'live' show that the value is already in use you'd have to look at AJAX.

Comment: I have already done that. If you read my question carefully, you will see that my problem is displaying the message afterwards. Because I want the message to maintain the same style as those that html generates for incorrect datatypes or empty required fields

Comment: if  you check for the amount of rows, you can just echo out an error message right? @amygrimaldi

Comment: Again, read the question. I want to maintain the same format as that for other incorrect input (violation of datatype, required, min, max, pattern etc)

Comment: What you are saying doesn't really make sense @amygrimaldi show us your code in your main post and I will explain why.

Comment: The code is a standard one. I will post it in the question. But i dont see the problem in my question. I dont want to just echo the error message. I want to echo it in a certain format.

Comment: Well then just echo it with HTML tags?

Comment: You can echo ANY html tag, meaning that you can customize the error in ANY way you want it. @amygrimaldi